# shift count greater than width of type

Tags: c, types

I have a function that takes an `int data_length` and does the following:

```
unsigned char *message = (unsigned char*)malloc(65535 * sizeof(char));
message[2] = (unsigned char)((data_length >> 56) & 255);
```

I'm getting the following:

```
warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   message[2] = (unsigned char)((data_length >> 56) & 255);
```

The program works as expected, but how can I remove the compiler warning (without disabling it)?
Similar questions didn't seem to use a variable as the data to be inserted so it seemed the solution was to cast them to int or such.

Comment: How is `data_length` declared?

Comment: Shifting an N-bit value by a negative number of bits, or shifting it by N or more bits, is undefined behaviour.  Anything can happen.  Unless `data_length` is a 64-bit type, your code exhibits UB.  Since the compiler is warning, `data_length` is not a 64-bit type.  Note that some compilers will treat the shift 'modulo number of bits in the type'; for a shift of 56 bits, such compilers would do a 24-bit shift on a 32-bit `data_length`.  That's a legitimate way to handle UB — your code should not rely on it.

Comment: U.B. means you can be lucky and get your expected behaviour, or you can switch compiler and get completely different behaviour (program crash or loop forever, are examples of something can happen)  Your program could work, but it is highly nonportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple. You're using `data_length` as `int` when it should be **unsigned** as negative lengths hardly make sense. Also to be able to shift 56 bits the value **must be** at least <s>56</s> 57 bits wide. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

In practice processors are known to do wildly different things. In one, shifting a 32-bit value right by 32 bits will clear the variable. In another, the value is shifted by 0 bits (`32 % 32`!). And then in some, perhaps the processor considers it invalid opcode and the OS kills the process.

Simple solution: declare `uint64_t data_length`.

---

If you really have limited yourself to 32-bit datatypes, then you can just assign 0 to these bytes that signify the most significant bytes. Or just cast to `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` before the shift.

Answer (score 3):

Shifting by an amount greater than the bit width of the type in question is not allowed by the standard, and doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This is detailed in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators.

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The
>   type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   If 
>   the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than
>   or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.

If the program appears to be working, it is by luck.  You could make a unrelated change to your program or simply build it on a different machine and suddenly things will stop working.

If the size of `data_length` is 32 bits or less, then shifting right by 56 is too big.  You can only shift by 0 - 31.