# ppc EXTDRI instruction equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, bit-manipulation, powerpc, instructions

Could someone show me an example in C++ of what this PowerPC instruction would look like?

From what I get, we are looking 44 bits shifted to the right inside of `r0`, and from there we are extracting the first 8 bits

```
extrdi    r0, r0, 8,44
```

Comment: Right-shift operator is `>>`. `&0xFF` will mask off the last 8 bits.

Answer (score 4):

The ISA says `extrdi` is 'Extract and right justify immediate', and it's an extended mnemonic for `rldicl` ('Rotate left double-word immediate and clear left') - v2.07 pg 717. So your statement is equivalent to `rldicl r0, r0, 52, 56`.

So, you want to extract 8 bits starting at position 44, and then right justify it, which would make it the least-significant 8 bits. It's worth noting that IBM bit numbers go the opposite way to what you'd probably expect: `conventional bit = 63 - IBM bit`. So IBM bits 44 to 51 are 'conventional' bit number 12 to 19.

We simply shift down so that bit 12 becomes bit 0 and bit 19 becomes bit 7 - a shift of 12 places. We then need to mask it so we only get the least-significant 8 bits.

```
unsigned long extrdi(unsigned long a) {
  return (a >> 12) & 0xff;
}
```

Looking on godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/rGe3EW, we see this is indeed:

```
extrdi:
        rldicl 3,3,52,56
        blr
        .long 0
        .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

(r3 is the argument and return register)

Comment: If you need to convert IBM to regular bit numbers a lot, try https://ozlabs.org/~matt/files/BitOrderingConverterSheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to [PowerPC mnemonics document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=em6bfprsi-64-bit-rotate-shift-extended-mnemonics-power-family-powerpc), `extrdi` means *extract n bits since bit b, then right-justify it*.

Take an 8-bit integer to illustrate:

```
extrdi r0, r0, 2, 3

r0: A B C D E F G H
        |   |
        +---+
        2 2+3-1

After extraction:    0 0 C D E 0 0 0
After justification: 0 0 0 0 0 C D E
```

We can implement as below (64-bit):

```c
unsigned long extrdi_soft(unsigned long ry, unsigned n, unsigned b) {
  unsigned offset = (64 - b - n);
  // Generate the n-bit mask beginning from position b
  unsigned mask = ((1UL << n) - 1) << offset;
  // Do mask and right-justify it
  return (ry & mask) >> offset;
}
```

Compare it against real `extrdi`:

```c
unsigned long extrdi_hard(unsigned long rs) {
  unsigned long ra = 0;
  asm("extrdi %1, %0, 8, 44"
     :"=r"(ra)
     :"r"(rs));
  return ra;
}

// extrdi_hard(0x1234567UL) == extrdi_soft(0x1234567UL, 8, 44)
```

`extrdi rs, ry, n, b` is actually mnemonic to `rldicl rs, ry, b+n, 64-n`. The instruction means *rotate left then clear left*. So we got another way to implement `extrdi`:

```c
unsigned long rotl64(unsigned long rs, unsigned n) {
  return (rs << n) | (rs >> (64-n));
}

unsigned long rldicl(unsigned long rs, unsigned sh, unsigned mb) {
  return rotl64(rs, sh) & ((1UL << (64 - mb)) - 1);
}

unsigned long extrdi(unsigned long ry, unsigned n, unsigned b) {
  return rldicl(ry, b+n, 64-n);
}
```

Comment: Your `rotl64` is good for illustration purposes but has undefined behaviour for `n=0` (`rs >> 64` is an out-of-range shift count, assuming `unsigned long` is `uint64_t`).  In modern C++, just use `std::rotl` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl .  To write your own UB-free rotate that compiles to a single instruction, see [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508)

Comment: Is there any reference that `u << 0` or `u >> sizeof(u)` is UB? From C and C++ standard doc, I only see shl/shr are translated as `u*2^n`/`u/2^n`, and `-pedantic -Wall` doesn't trigger any error.

Comment: `u >> (sizeof(u)*CHAR_BIT)` is UB. An answer on [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817045) quotes one of the standards.  Or [shift count greater than width of type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52784451) was the second hit for `site:stackoverflow.com shift count ub`